# Funciones no válidas, primer encuentro frustrado

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

```
      return  (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/listado" element ={ (props) => <Listado addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} {...props}  />} />
          <Route path="/detalle" element={<Detalle />} />
          <Route path="/resultados" element={ (props) => <Resultados  addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/favoritos" element={  (props) => <Favoritos  favorites={favorites}  addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs} {...props} />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: ¿Qué son los `<>` y `</>` que están rodeando al `<BrowserRouter>`?

Comment: @Jacobo es una sintaxis corta para declara un <React.Fragment> con el detalle de que <> no acepta llaves/atributos

Comment: No hubiese podido contestarte mejor jacobo , gracias @StialManstike

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en que `element` no puede aceptar una función. Tú estás usando una función en lugar de un componente para hacer tu render.
La forma correcta de usar componentes en una ruta y poder pasarles los `props` se hace mediante la etiqueta `render`. Por lo tanto, tú código debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
return (
  <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />

          <Route path="/listado"
            render={(props) =>
              <Listado
                {...props}
                addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs}
              />
            }
            exact={true} />

          <Route path="/detalle" element={<Detalle />} />

          <Route path="/resultados"
            render={(props) =>
              <Resultados
                {...props}
                addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs}
              />
            }
            exact={true} />

          <Route path="/favoritos"
            render={(props) =>
              <Favoritos
                {...props}
                addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs}
              />
            }
            exact={true} />
        </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Lo apliqué y me dice: Matched leaf route at location "/Listado" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el código de tu pregunta?

Comment: no me dejaba publicarlo entero en este mensaje asi que lo pegué abajo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No publiques el código como respuesta.

Comment: Intenta agregar los exact a tus otras rutas.

Comment: ya lo hice... <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
  
            <Route path="/listado"
              render={(props) =>
                <Listado
                  {...props}
                  addOrRemoveFromFavs={addOrRemoveFromFavs}
                />
              }
              exact={true} />